# How to geographically filter entries in PySpark?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I have a dataset of locations in Lat/Lon format of users in a time period and I would like to filter the entries using GIS functions. For example, finding entries inside a polygon (ST_Contains from the GIS world) and  using an [ESRI geodatabase](http://www.gadm.org/country) file to add a column that is the district that user entry is located in.

I have searched the web and found [Magellan](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan), but the Python support is [not working](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan/issues/59#issuecomment-240209859) at this time. I have also found Hive support for GIS functions in [Esri Spatial](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop%20Esri%20Spatial), but didn't find documentation on how to load the correct package when starting up PySpark or how to register the needed functions in the PySpark shell: (ST_Polygon, ST_Contains, etc...).

Are there other alternatives that I should look into? I am using Azure's HDInsight so I have access to a HiveContext object in the PySpark shell:

```
>>> sqlContext
<pyspark.sql.context.HiveContext object at 0x7f3294093b10>
```

Sample dataset:

> | Timestamp| User| Latitude|Longitude|
>   |1462838468|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1462838512|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1462838389|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1462838497|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1465975885|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1457723815|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1457897289|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177922|-7.447443|
>   |1457899229|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177922|-7.447443|
>   |1457972626|405C238E25FE0B9E7...| 37.18059| -7.46128|
>   |1458062553|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1458241825|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.178172|-7.444512|
>   |1458244457|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.178172|-7.444512|
>   |1458412513|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1458412292|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1465197963|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465202192|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923817|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923766|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923748|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923922|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any python library with Spark, no need for the library to be Spark specific. Some GIS python libraries recommended by some random search are at http://spatialdemography.org/essential-python-geospatial-libraries/

You would have to install the library you want to use. Instructions on how to install libraries can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38754345/1663781

Then, simply add a column to your RDD using any of the libraries, like so:

```
from my_gis_library_of_choice import in_polygon, district

text_lines = sc.textFile('wasb:///mydataset')
split = text_lines.map(lambda line: line.split('|'))
with_extra_columns = split.map(lambda r: r.append(in_polygon(r[2], r[3])).append(district(r[2], r[3])))
```